# Document classification: Preprocessing and multiple labels

Tags: word2vec, text-classification, tf-idf, doc2vec

I have a question about the word representation algorithms:
Which one of the algorithms word2Vec, doc2Vec and Tf-IDF is more suitable for handling text classification tasks ?
The corpus used in my supervised learning classification is composed of a list of multiple sentences, with both short length sentences and long length ones. As discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643074/document-similarity-vector-embedding-versus-tf-idf-performance), doc2vec vs word2vec choice is a matter of document length. As for Tf-Idf vs. word embedding, it's more a matter of text representation.

My other question is, what if for the same corpus I had more than one label to link to the sentences in it ? If I create multiple entries/labels for the same sentence, it affects the decision of the final classification algorithm. How can I tell the model that every label counts equal for every sentence of the document ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try multiple methods of turning your sentences into 'feature vectors'. There are no hard-and-fast rules; what works best for your project will depend a lot on your specific data, problem-domains, & classification goals.

(Don't extrapolate guidelines from other answers – such as the one you've linked that's about document-similarity rather than classification – as best practices for your project.)

To get initially underway, you may want to focus on some simple 'binary classification' aspect of your data, first. For example, pick a single label. Train on all the texts, merely trying to predict if that one label applies or not.

When you have that working, so you have a understanding of each step – corpus prep, text processing, feature-vectorization, classification-training, classification-evaluation – then you can try extending/adapting those steps to either single-label classification (where each text should have exactly one unique label) or multi-label classification (where each text might have any number of combined labels).